# C++ raw pointers and "delete"

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a question regarding the code snippet below:

```
double d = 20.1;
double* pd = new double;
...
pd = &d;
delete pd;
```

The last line throws an error in Visual C++ 2015. Does this mean that the pointer "`pd`" points to the stack address of "`d`" and its original pointed-to address in the heap (right-hand side of the equal sign in the second line) has leaked?

Comment: Yes, that's what's going on.

Comment: `delete` needs the pointer value which resulted from `new`. It's irrelevant whether that's named by a variable that was immediately initialized from that result. And here the variable no longer has that correct value.

Comment: You're not only leaking, you're invoking UB by `delete`ing an address not obtained by calling `new`.

Comment: When you assign to a variable, you lose the original value of the variable. For a pointer that means you lose where it originally pointed. What your doing is somewhat similar to `int a = 10; a = 20;` and then wonder why `a` isn't equal to `10` anymore.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you leaked the double originally pointer by `pd`, but that's not what's causing the error.

The error is a result of you trying to `delete` a stack allocated address. That is is strictly undefined behavior. `delete` will only work for pointers which were created with `new`.

Answer (score 1):

Variables hold values. Pointer values are just that, values. Not names. Not variables.

When you manipulate a pointer value, for example to pass it to `delete`, you only care about the value.

It's essentially equivalent to:

```
int one=1;
one=2;
std::cout << one; // you won't be surprised to see 2, will you?
```

The value currently in the variable matters; not some previous value. Not the name.

Your program tries to deallocate (`delete`) an object that wasn't allocated by you (the user), but by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

> Does this mean that the pointer "`pd`" points to the stack address of "`d`" and its original pointed-to address in the heap (right-hand side of the equal sign in the second line) has leaked?

Yes, that is *exactly* what this means.